# JavaScript Cookie Visit Count, Last Login Date

Tags: javascript, cookies, visitor-pattern

I'm new to JavaScript and cookies and I'm trying to create one that will display the amount of times someone has visited a site, the last time they visited, and the expiry date of the cookie.

So far I've taken code from W3schools and tried to modify it to my needs with no luck, then I tried [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-deal-with-cookies-in-javascript/).  What I have now is an amalgamation of both...

**JavaScript**

```
function createCookie(name, value, expires) {
    var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";

    document.cookie = cookie;

function getCookie(name)  {
    var regexp = new RegExp("(?:^" + name + "|;\s*"+ name + ")=(.*?)(?:;|$)", "g");
    var result = regexp.exec(document.cookie);
    return (result === null) ? null : result[1];
}

function checkCookie()  {
    var visLog = getCookie("visLog");
    var visAmt = 0;
    var logDate = new Date();
    //create lastLog logDate storage


    if (visLog != null)  {
        visAmt++;
        alert("You've visited this page: " + visAmt + " times." \n
            "Last visited: " + logDate + "." \n
            "This cookie will stop tracking: " + expires);
    }else{
        createCookie("visLog", "visits", "December 31, 2013 12:59:59");
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

Edit: Grammar.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason you are doing this from a cookie instead of from your application database? The cookie would only display the information if the user used the same browser on the same machine. Typically this kind of thing is stored in a DB along with the user login info.

---

It might be easier to implement with localStorage instead, since most browsers have it now:

```
function updateVisitInfo() {
    localStorage.lastVisit = new Date();
    localStorage.numVisits = (localStorage.numVisits || 0) + 1;
}

function printVisitInfo() {
    alert("You've visited this page: " + (localStorage.numVisits || 0) + " times." \n
        "Last visited: " + (localStorage.lastVisit || "never") + "."
}
```

Comment: I'll consider this, try to implement it.  This is for a school assignment.  I could easily copy what is on W3Schools and modify that slightly to complete the assignment, but I want to do a bit more.  I just don't know where I'm going wrong, exactly.

Comment: I tried your solution.  Nothing happened.  I think there is a problem with my checkCookie() function.  I still have no idea, though.

Comment: What browser are you using, and how are you loading your web page? From a server, or off your hard drive at a file:// location?

Comment: At first I was trying to load the page off my computer, but then I noticed some issues with that.  Since then I've been working off a server.  I'm using Chrome, but the page needs to be compatible with IE, Firefox, and Chrome at the least.